# Ansible search content of variable in another variable

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to check if the content of variable B is in variable ssl_certs.
The following works, but gives me a warning:

```
[WARNING]: conditional statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}.
```

Working playbook:

```
  vars:
    B: 'test-cert'

  tasks:

  - name: Collect bigip facts
    bigip_device_facts:
      provider: '{{ provider }}'
      gather_subset: ssl-certs
    register: ssl_certs

  - name: debug SSL cert exists
    debug:
      msg: "cert-test already exists"
    when: ssl_certs is search('{{B}}')
```

If I just add the content of B in search, I can get rid of the warning. But how do I search the content of one var being in another var for the conditional statement?

I have tried the following, which doesnt work as no exact match

```
when: "B == ssl_certs"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, given the line below is in the text stored in *ssl_certs*

```
         Subject: CN=Jane Doe, OU=Finance, O=test-cert, C=US
```

Jinja test [*in*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-tests.in) is the simplest way of testing whether the content of *B* is in the text stored in *ssl_certs* or not. The task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: cert-test already exists
      when: B in ssl_certs
      vars:
        B: test-cert
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: cert-test already exists
```

The same result gives the Ansible test [*search*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings)

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: cert-test already exists
      when: ssl_certs is search(B)
      vars:
        B: test-cert
```

This test can be used to search for more details, .e.g

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: cert-test already exists
      when: ssl_certs is search(regex)
      vars:
        B: test-cert
        regex: 'Subject:(.*)O={{ B }}'
```

Comment: `when: ssl_certs is search(B)` works perfect. thank you

Answer (score 0):

**The when clause is a raw Jinja2 expression without double curly braces.**
You can try this code snippet.
vars:
B: 'test-cert'

```
  tasks:

  - name: Collect bigip facts
    bigip_device_facts:
      provider: '{{ provider }}'
      gather_subset: ssl-certs
    register: ssl_certs

  - name: debug SSL cert exists
    debug:
      msg: "cert-test already exists"
    when: ssl_certs in B
```

Ansibles' parser parses the when conditional at runtime and since it is a raw jinja2 template we do not need to provide the '{{}}' of jinja2 templates.